# iOS app is crashing on ios 13 and with Xcode 11 when it didn't before

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios13, xcode11

Our app is crashing with the fatal exception:

```
Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread.
```

Our app used to not throw this exception on previous versions of iOS (12 and below) and when I would compile on Xcode 10. Now, on iOS 13.3.1 and compiling on Xcode 11.3.1 our app crashes 10 seconds after opening every time. I looked into this exception and it seems Apple has decided to prevent apps from accessing the `UIKit` on background threads (please correct me if I'm wrong here). After enabling the **Main Thread Checker** I was able to pinpoint the line that was causing this crash. Backtracing the code led me to this line:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //Code that uses the StoreKit to retrieve purchase data, 
    //then updates the UI using UIKit based on this information
});
```

This code is fine though right? Because even though it's dispatching this block of code, it's doing it to the main thread, so this shouldn't be the issue, correct? Well, even after moving this block of code out of the `dispatch_async()` function, it still crashes. So then I looked at the singleton for this class, which looks like this:

```
+(instancetype)sharedPurchaseManager
{
    static PurchaseManager * sharedPurchaseManager = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedPurchaseManager = [[PurchaseManager alloc] _init];
    });
    return sharedPurchaseManager;
}
```

And I wondered if the `_init()` for the `PurchaseManager` was happening in a background thread. So I tried moving the allocation for `PurchaseManager` out of the `dispatch_once()` block and the app stopped crashing. Furthermore, the **Main Thread Checker** stopped interrupting the program at the line that uses `UIKit`. I'm pretty sure that moving my `_init()` code out of the `dispatch_once()` block is not the correct way to go about fixing my issue, as this is the standard singleton design pattern (please correct me if I'm wrong). So then how should I go about fixing this issue? Furthermore, we have about 10+ crashes in our code that is due to the same exception, and with a similar design pattern to our `PurchaseManager`, so we would want a solution for all of these exceptions.

Comment: Can you upload code inside of `[[PurchaseManager alloc] _init]` function? maybe there is some code that requires Main thread in the init function

Comment: Yeah there's definitely UI code inside the `_init` function that requires the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `[[PurchaseManager alloc] _init]` contains some UI code, but `+(instancetype)sharedPurchaseManager` is accessed first time from background thread.

So you can try two approaches:

1) find the way explicitly initialize `sharedPurchaseManger` on the main thread (eg. in applicationDidFinishLaunching)

2) try to use the following

```
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ // << intentionally synchronous!
       sharedPurchaseManager = [[PurchaseManager alloc] _init];
    }
});
```